# Hard code date comparison in case statement

Tags: sql-server, case, date-comparison

Need help in getting the first date when `getdate` falls in between two dates.
Tried with the below code, but syntax is incorrect. I would like to get the output as `2018-09-29` from the below code:

```
 DECLARE @Fromdt datetime

 set @fromdt= (select case 
                when getdate()>='2018-09-01' and  getdate()<='2018-09-13' then '2018-09-01'
                when getdate()>='2018-09-15' and  getdate()<='2018-09-27' then '2018-09-27'
                when getdate()>='2018-09-29' and  getdate()<='2018-10-10' then '2018-09-29'
                when getdate()>='2018-10-12' and  getdate()<='2018-10-24' then '2018-10-12' 
  end as frmdt from table1)

select @frmdt
```

Comment: maybe you can explain what are you trying to achieve here ? Your query select from `table`1` but i don't see any where else you reference any column from any table at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query variable name in declaration and selection is not same and i just remove `from table1` it works fine

```
DECLARE @Fromdt datetime    
 set @fromdt= (select case 
                when getdate()>='2018-09-01' and  getdate()<='2018-09-13' then '2018-09-01'
                when getdate()>='2018-09-15' and  getdate()<='2018-09-27' then '2018-09-27'
                when getdate()>='2018-09-29' and  getdate()<='2018-10-10' then '2018-09-29'
                when getdate()>='2018-10-12' and  getdate()<='2018-10-24' then '2018-10-12' 
  end as frmdt)

select @Fromdt
```

Below link is fiddle link where i just check your query

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fbdf363ef76e176c4cf34f63cf07cfab

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the query that you want

```
select @fromdt = case 
                 when getdate()>='2018-09-01' and  getdate()<='2018-09-13' then '2018-09-01'
                 when getdate()>='2018-09-15' and  getdate()<='2018-09-27' then '2018-09-27'
                 when getdate()>='2018-09-29' and  getdate()<='2018-10-10' then '2018-09-29'
                 when getdate()>='2018-10-12' and  getdate()<='2018-10-24' then '2018-10-12' 
                 end
```

note that `getdate()` returns date & time. If you only interested in the date alone, you can use `convert(date, getdate())` to convert to date only

You can declare a current_date variable and use that in your query

```
declare @current_date date
select @current_date = getdate();
```